# Marginal effects model with ggpredict() for a generalized poisson linear model

Tags: poisson-regression, marginal-effect, underdispersion

I am working with count data of mosquito abundance and I want to isolate the effect of land-use from the effect of topographic variables. Therefore, I'm combining a poison regression model with `ggpredict` from the `ggeffects` package to calculate the marginal effects. However, my data is underdispersed (dispersion test gave a dispersion of 0.03) and I understand that a generalized poisson model might therefore be better. However, `vglm` model (which I use for the generalized poisson model) does not seem to be supported by `ggpredict`. Does anyone know another option to get marginal effects using generalized poisson models? Could I also use the quasi-poisson model for underdispersion?

```r
#create dataframe from raster files, 
#dataframe has columns with the following 
#variables: #LCC(mosquitoes; count), 
#forest(land-use class; categoric), 
#DEM/DEM_asp/DEM_sl (topographic #variables; 
#continuous), X/Y (coordinates; not used for 
#this question), group (not used for this 
#question)
df_s <- stack(gen.r, forest_rcl, DEM, 
    DEM_asp, DEM_sl)
df <- data.frame(values(df_s))
df$forest <- as.factor(df[,2])
df$LCC <- df[,1] 
df$X <- coordinates(forest_rcl)[,1]
df$Y <- coordinates(forest_rcl)[,2]
df <- na.omit(df)
levels(df$forest) <- 
       levels(forest_rcl)[[1]][2:7, 2]
#rename dataframe
df_er_DEM <- df

data <- df_er_DEM

#linear models
model1 <- glm(LCC ~ forest*DEM + 
       forest:aspect + forest:slope, 
       data=data, family='poisson')
model2 <- vglm(LCC ~ forest*DEM + 
            forest:aspect + forest:slope, 
            data=data, family=genpoisson)

# data does seem to follow a poisson 
# distribution
ggplot(data, aes(LCC)) + geom_histogram()
pchisq(model1$deviance, model1$df.residual, 
        lower.tail = FALSE)
fit <- goodfit(data$LCC, 'poisson')
summary(fit)
# dispersion= 0.03
dispersiontest(model1)

#marginal effects; does not work with model2
ggpredict(model1, 'forest')
```